# Jquery toggle effect not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

So basically I have a div which I would like to make some kind of animation with, first I tried to toggle the div then completely remove the div from the DOM using .remove() jquery function. But the problem that I'm having right now is that the toggle effects is not taking place, it is just going straight to the remove() code. I tried to delayed the code but same thing happened. Can someone help me to understand why my codes is behaving like that? Please run the snippet below you will notice that theres not toggle effect.

```js
function remv(){
  $(".myDiv").toggle( "clip" );
  $(".myDiv").remove();
  
  
  alert('PORTUGAL IS GOIN TO WIN THE WORLD CUP AND CANT DO    NOTHING ABOUT IT!');
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Portugal will be winner of the fifa world cup 2018";
  
  
  
}
```

```css
.myDiv{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<center><h3><p id="test">Click on the surprise box</p></h3></center>
<center>

<div class="myDiv" onclick="remv()"></div><br>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to call `.remove()` in the 'complete' callback of `.toggle()` so it will wait for the animation to complete.

```
$(".myDiv").toggle("clip", function() {
    $(".myDiv").remove();
});
```

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```js
function remv() {
$(".myDiv").toggle(
    "clip",
    function() {
        $(".myDiv").remove();
                
        alert('PORTUGAL IS GOIN TO WIN THE WORLD CUP AND CANT DO    NOTHING ABOUT IT!');
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Winner of the fifa world cup 2018";
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    }
);
}
```

```css
.myDiv{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<center><h3><p id="test">Click on the surprise box</p></h3></center>
<center>
<div id="dialog" >
  
  <img src="https://i.gifer.com/JgI9.gif" alt="Placeholder Image" />

</div>
<div class="myDiv" onclick="remv()"></div><br>
</center>
</div>
  <script>
   $( "#dialog" ).hide();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function remv(){
  $(".myDiv").toggle( "clip" );
  $(".myDiv").remove();
  
  
  alert('PORTUGAL IS GOIN TO WIN THE WORLD CUP AND CANT DO    NOTHING ABOUT IT!');
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML="Portugal will be winner of the fifa world cup 2018";
  
  
  
}
```

```css
.myDiv{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color: orange;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<center><h3><p id="test">Click on the surprise box</p></h3></center>
<center>

<div class="myDiv" onclick="remv()"></div><br>
</center>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```